# Appcelerator APP with add's, using AdMob or StartApp

Tags: ios, admob, appcelerator, startapp

Good Morning,

I'm trying to implement Google Admob or StartApp to have add's in my iOS app, made in Appcelerator and JS.

I found a tutorial at:

https://medium.com/appseed-io/integrate-admob-with-appcelerator-titanium-34f081d4ad30

But I need a module called Ti.Admob and I can't find it to download.

Does anyone have an example that works with AdMob or StartApp, or know where I can download the Ti.Admob module?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the module here: https://github.com/tidev/ti.admob

But the latest update can be downloaded here: https://github.com/Astrovic/ti.admob

Here's an example app with ti.admob: https://github.com/Astrovic/ti.admob-sample-app

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I have tried to use the model from the link you provided  (https://github.com/Astrovic/ti.admob), but after using the example that cames with it, the app closes alone in opening. do you know why?